# Projective modules of rank $n$ over a ring with $\operatorname{Pic}(R) = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-k-theory

> Let $R$ a ring with trivial Picard group, so every rank $1$ projective module is free.  *What does that tell me about the structure of projective modules of rank $n$*?

For starters, if $P$ is any projective module of rank $n$ then $P$ will have trivial determinant, because $\bigwedge^n P$ will have constant rank $1$ and be trivial by assumption.

Furthermore, the relation $Pic(A \times B) \cong Pic(A) \times Pic(B)$  forces any projection of $R$ to have trivial Picard group, so when we form the componentwise determinant of any finitely generated projective module it will be also be trivial.

But this is as far as I get... lots of trivial determinants, but to what end?

I know that there are examples of rings with $Pic(R) = 0$ and even non-free rank $2$ projective modules, such as mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54356/nonfree-projective-module-over-a-regular-ufd).  On the other hand, semi-local rings (or more generally rings which are $0$-dimensional modulo their Jacobson radicals) are examples of rings over which any rank $n$ projective modules are free.

To give some context, I am trying to show that every projective rank $n$ module of some special class of rings are free (I'm pretty sure they are).  I am able to show it for $n=1$ by constructing explicit (and fairly elaborate) isomorphisms, but I have no idea how to generalize the construction, because my knowledge of invertible modules doesn't extend to higher ranks.  My hope is that there is some theory I am missing that will bridge the gap!

> How does one go about generalizing knowledge about invertible modules to higher ranks?

**EDIT**: Actually I think there might be a 'dimension-shifting' approach that I had missed the first time around.  Namely, if we know that rank $n$ projectives are free, then consider a rank $n+1$ projective and the evaluation homomorphism $P \otimes_R \operatorname{Hom}(P, R) \rightarrow R$ which one checks locally must be surjective.  This gives a short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow P \otimes_R \operatorname{Hom}(P, R) \rightarrow R \rightarrow 0$ which splits, so $K$ is seen to be a rank $n$ projective, and by hypothesis free.  Thus we have $P \otimes_R \operatorname{Hom}(P, R) \cong R^{n+1}$.  Of course this doesn't finish the argument, but it puts us in good position to generalize a construction from invertible modules to higher ranks.  Still curious to hear if anyone else has ideas!
**EDIT2**: That last edit didn't make any sense because actually $K$ would then have rank $n^2 - 1$ which is useless, but maybe there's still some merit in the approach.

Comment: You can not say much about higher rank projective modules. As you observed, for a Noetherian ring of dimension one, any projective module is free plus rank one, so with your assumption, they are free. Unless you have much more information, you will not find anything useful in the literature.